# How do I list files installed by a package from the AUR?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, pacman

I'm using arch-linux and I have installed a package from the aur. I want to know what changes it has made to my computer (specifically which files it has installed). Is this information available, and if so, what command do I use to get the information?

I've tried `pacman -F...` with various options but this seems to only work with packages from the repositories. I'm happy use a tool like `yaourt` or `aura` if that is necessary.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`-F` is just like `-S` and accesses pacman's database of available repository packages – which does not include AUR because that's not a pacman repository (unless you're using a third-party "prebuilt AUR packages" repository).

In this case you want to query the database of *locally installed* packages, which includes everything that's installed right now (regardless of source), which is done through `-Q`:

```
pacman -Ql package_name
```